# How to change src of img within an area tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the src of an img which is within area tags in a map using javascript. Do I do it the same way as normal images or not? The code is:

```
<img name="img_1" src="image-1.png" usemap="#imgMap" id="img1">
<map name="imgMap"><area shape="circle" coords="499, 724, 23" onmouseover="[change image code]">
</map>
```

Can someone write a JavaScript function which changes image1 and replaces it with image2? Preferably no JQuery please. I need to use this method several times and therefore specifically need a function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First give your image an id. This makes it easier the javascript. then use this code:

```
document.getElementById("img1").src = "/link/to/new/image";
```

Comment: Technically you don't need an ID. `document.querySelector("[usemap='#"+this.parentNode.getAttribute("name")+"']")` would get it reliably, but is rather long-winded. I might put something like this in a function so I can just do `getMapImage(this)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS:

```
#imageId:hover
{
    background-image: url('image-2.png');
}
```

That is, if I understand your question correctly, please edit your question to make it more clear if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is indeed the better option, but he asked for a javascript solution.

Comment: @Jerodev He asked for no jQuery (and okay, It's tagged JavaScript but I'm assuming that OP didn't know better), I understand that this could be done with JavaScript but this is a way better option so it's up to him whether he wants to use it or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function:

```
<script>
    function changeImageArea(imageId, newSrc)
    {
        var img = document.getElementById(imageId);

        if (img)
        {
             img.src = newSrc;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

And here is how you use your function:

```
<img name="img_1" src="image-1.png" usemap="#imgMap" id="img1">
  <map name="imgMap"><area shape="circle" coords="499, 724, 23" onmouseover="[change image code]">
  </map>

<script>changeImageArea('img1', 'http://www.somesite.com/image.jpg');</script>
```

Remember to keep the JavaScript code below your HTML code. This will avoid reference problems.
Hope this can help you.